# Strange UpdatePanel and Extender control error

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the below markup in a master page, and when I access a page using that master, I get the error:

> An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it
>   extends.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel99" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function OnAutoCompleteSelected(source, eventArgs) {
        $("#autoCompleteHidden").val(eventArgs._text);
        __doPostBack("autoCompleteHidden", "");
      }
    </script>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 25px">Search By
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearchBy" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSearchBy_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem>Emp No</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>ID No</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Surname</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnSearch" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Apps/mySearch2.png"
            Width="20px" OnClick="imgBtnSearch_Click" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="height: 25px; margin-left: 80px;">
          <div>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="autoCompleteHidden" OnValueChanged="autoCompleteHidden_ValueChanged" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchField" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtSearchField"
              ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetEmployees" Enabled="False" CompletionInterval="100"
              MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionSetCount="10000" OnClientItemSelected="OnAutoCompleteSelected"
              CompletionListCssClass="CompletionList" CompletionListItemCssClass="CompletionListItem" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="CompletionListHighlightedItem">
            </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

There is only one UpdatePanel on the master page, and the extended control, `txtSearchField` is contained well within it only. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another `AutoCompleteExtender` for the same textbox outside of the `UpdatePanel`.